# Is any way to split long string in CMakePresets.json?

Tags: json, cmake, cmake-presets

I have so long LIB and PATH variables in configurations, is any way to split them for readability ?

Comment: CMake treats `CMakePresets.json` as a file in JSON format. So, whether you can split long lines fully depends on the format itself. Unfortunately, JSON doesn't allow such splitting.